# xslt select="." vs select="<tag name>"

Tags: xslt

I am finally beginning to understand how xslt works.
Since I will be creating several more xslts in the future I would like to write them well.
I am wondering whether there is a preferred way to get the data of an xml tag.
Is it better to use select="." select=" tag name " or is it irrelevant?

For example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
    or
<xsl:value-of select="Vert_Prism" />
```

To get the data enclosed in the Vert_Prism tag.

```
<Vert_Prism>1.5</Vert_Prism>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your context. If your current node is `Vert_Prism`, then you would use `<xsl:value-of select="." />` to get the text value of the current node.

OTOH, `<xsl:value-of select="Vert_Prism" />` is an abbreviation of  `<xsl:value-of select="child::Vert_Prism" />` - so this would not return anything, unless the current `Vert_Prism` has a child element with the same name. However, it would work fine from the context of the parent node of `Vert_Prism`.

Comment: michael.hor257k, in this case it would be the current node.

Comment: @JMW Good. So is your question answered?

Comment: what I am really wondering is which is the better coding style.  select="." or select=" tag name " or does it matter?

Comment: As I tried to explain, it is not a matter of style. These two are not the same, One selects the current node, the other selects the current node's children.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  In looking at your comment, I see what you are saying but ...  In this case, Vert_Prism has no children unless the text 1.5 of that element is a child.  Is that the case?  It seems I still have a lot to learn about xslt and xpath.

Comment: Yes, the text node "1.5" is a child of the `Vert_Prism` element. Why is that a "but"?